# Showing irreducibility in $\mathbb Z[X]$ for a quartic polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $f(X) = X^4 - 10X^2 + 11 \in \mathbb Z[X]$ and let $\bar f(X) \in \mathbb Z_7[X]$ be the polynomial obtained from $f(X)$ by reduction modulo 7.
> By using the factorisation of $\bar f(X)$ or otherwise, show that  $f(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

What I have done so far is to factorise $\bar f(X)$ as a product of monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb Z_7[X]$, getting that $\bar f(X) = (X^2 + \bar 2)^2$.

What I am struggling with is how to use this to show that $f(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

My idea is to show this by contradiction, assuming that $f(X)$ *is* reducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$, but I'm unsure where to go from there.

Comment: $X^4 - 10X^2 + 11$ is irreducible mod 3: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+X%5E4+-+10X%5E2+%2B+11+mod+3)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a continuation of your method, notice that the reduction into irreducibles in $\mathbb Z_7$ as you've done demonstrates that if the polynomial is reducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$, we have

$f(X)=(X^2+aX+b)(X^2+cX+d)$ where both of these factors are $X^2+\bar{2}$ after reduction mod $7$. That means that $b,d\equiv 2 \bmod 7$, but $bd=11$ causes a contradiction.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I was thinking $b,d\in \mathbb Z$ so $bd=11$ implies $\{b,d\}=\{1,11\} $or $\{-1,-11\}$. Does this work?

Comment: +1 Fairly sure this is the intended way.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[X]$, because $f(X+1)=X^4+4X^3-4X^2-16X+2$ is Eisenstein with $p=2$.

Also, $f$ is irreducible modulo $3$ (but not modulo $7$), and hence irreducible in $\Bbb Z[X]$ and $\Bbb Q[X]$.

Comment: In the first solution one can add: "and being monic it is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$".

Comment: @user26857 Yes, thank you. I wanted to write "in $\Bbb Z[X]$ and $\Bbb Q[X]$". Also, it is irreducible for $p=17$.